# Is it possible to attack a server by uploading / through uploaded files?

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, upload

the title actually tells the issue. And before you get me wrong, **I DO NOT want to know how this can be done**, but how I can **prevent** it.

I want to write a file uploader (in Java with JPA and MySQL database). Since I'm not yet 100% sure about the internal management, there is the possibility that at some point the file could be executed/opened internally.

So, therefor I'd be glad to know, what there is, an attacker can do to harm, infect or manipulate my system by uploading whatever type of file, may it be a media file, a binary or whatever.

For instance:

- What about special characters in the file name?
- What about manipulating meta data like EXIF?
- What about "embedded viruses" like in an MP3 file?

I hope this is not too vague and I'd be glad to read your tips and hints.

Best regards,
Stacky

Comment: I'd also appreciate hints to related literature!

Comment: Yes. It's called a [denial-of-service attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack). The particularly bad ones are [*distributed* denial-of-services attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack#Distributed_attack).

Comment: Yes, I know about DDoS, but this is a general problem which can happen to every server, wheather it's got a file uploader or not.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder DoS attacks have very little to do with (uploaded) file types. AFAIR it is more about the frequency of requests and there are many ways to counter that

Comment: @GermannArlington: DoS is DoS, you can do a DoS by uploading thousands of (presumably fake) files, consuming the bandwidth of the site, preventing legitimate users from uploads. The point is that it's a whole class of problems and the OP's tool would just be one way to do it.

Comment: @Stacky Unfortunately the most you can do is to make sure that you never save executable files with executable permissions on your system. There is hardly anything you can do to check the files for viruses apart from running some kind of anti-virus program on your server scanning all uploaded files (I don't like running anti-virus programs on the server for many reasons)

Comment: Limiting the file size and mime types your uploader supports is a start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really very application specific. If you're using a particular web app like phpBB, there are completely different security needs than if you're running a news group. If you want tailored security recommendations, you'll need to search for them based on the context of what you're doing. It could range from sanitizing input to limiting upload size and format.

For example, an MP3 file virus probably only works on a few specific MP3 players. Not on all of them.

At any rate, if you want broad coverage from viruses, then scan the files with a virus scanner, but that probably won't protect you from things like script injection.

Comment: Fair enough, but many people use to play MP3 files on their PC as well... ;-)

Comment: Never heard of an MP3 file virus, but its certainly possible that a *specific* player has a bug (probably some kind of buffer overflow) that allows an attack. Its certainly limited to *that* one player (or library) though, so simply choose another player.

Comment: Well, I've seen a report on that topic a while ago on a TV news mag. Unfortunately, I couldn't refind something similar, but concerning images, I found this:
http://www.intego.com/mac-security-blog/new-mac-trojan-discovered-related-to-syria/

Answer (score 1):

If your server doesn't do something *inherently stupid*, there should be no problem. But...

*Since I'm not yet 100% sure about the internal management, there is the possibility that at some point the file could be executed/opened internally.*

... this qualifies as inherently stupid. You *have* to make sure you don't accidently execute uploaded files (permissions on the upload directory are a starting point, limit the upload to specific directories etc.).

Aside from executing, if the server attempts any file type specific processing (e.g. make thumbnails of images) there is always the possibility that the processing can be attacked through buffer overflow exploits (these are specific for each type of software/library though).

A pure file server (e.g. FTP) that just stores/serves files is save (when there are no other holes).

Comment: By saying "not yet 100% sure", I didn't mean, I wouldn't know, what I was doing, but that I haven't made my final decisions on the features of the website, which will use the files on that server, because I don't want to "simply store" them. All that of course effects what the server will (have to) do with each file (i.e. encryption, conversion, use in background etc.).
But I appreciate your clarity in concern and warnings, so thank you.